# Network hierarchy with subnets

Tags: networking, subnet, hierarchy

Is it possible to divide networks with subnets so that they intersect?
My example is:

Network A: only visible inside network A
Network B: only visible inside network B
Network C: visible from both networks?

Can this be achieved with subnets or do I take a different approach?

The idea is to have some devices (printers) to be visible from every subnet, while the some devices are private to their own network (e g. Chromecast, so that you can cast only inside your own network).

Is there a simple solution? If it's not trivial: what would you recommend instead?

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 3):

Of course this is possible.

Set up routing between networks A and C, and between networks B and C, but not between networks A and B.